# Add a Post Thumbnail to an RSS Feed with custom size

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails, feed

I have two different blogs on the same domain and my goal is to get the 3 latest posts from blog1 to show on the home page of blog2. Everything goes well following these instructions: http://www.worldoweb.co.uk/2012/display-wordpress-posts-on-another-wp-blog

The problem comes when I want to style the image, I need them to have all the same size/proportion using the custom sizes in wordpress. To achieve this I use the following code on functions.php in blog1 but I keep getting the huge image, not the small one:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
add_image_size( 'home1-thumb', 630, 320, true );
}


//add post thumbnails to RSS images
function cwc_rss_post_thumbnail($content) {
   global $post;
     if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $content = '<p>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'home1-thumb') .
    '</p>' . get_the_excerpt();
     }
    return $content;
 }
 add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'cwc_rss_post_thumbnail');
 add_filter('the_content_feed', 'cwc_rss_post_thumbnail');
```

Edit: In case it's of any help, the feed we are talking about is http://institutoespanol.net/blog/feed/ It's running a 3.4.2 install as of now (I think it was on the previous version), I don't have much info on the server it's running on (what should I be looking for so I know what to ask?) and the list of plugins is unrelated to the problem but here it is:

Simple google analytics, regenerate thumbnails, google xml sitemaps, advanced custom fields, akismet, newsletter, Responsive Select Menu. Nothing cache related.

Comment: try using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ to regenerate you thumbnails.

Comment: yep, already using it, the thumbnails are there but the image being displayed by the feed is the big one (original size)

Comment: Update your questions with more details of your environment, server? WP version? any cache plugins in place?

Comment: I edited the question as suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after doing nothing, two days later it seems to be working. My guess is the RSS needed to update the images after changing the code (I did everything, checked if it was working, then tried to add the custom size for the image). Well atleast the code is right in case anyone needs to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

While your code is technically correct, there's one small change i'd do, just to prepend the thumbnail to the code. Using your code will break the Full Text / Summary admin setting.

```
function cwc_rss_post_thumbnail($content) {
    global $post;
    if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $precontent = '<p>' . get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_id()) .'</p>';
        $content = $precontent.$content;
    }
    return $content;
}
```